# How can I set focus to a Tabs on a page after submit?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

My page has a region with 2 tabs.

Tab1 , Tab2

On Tab1 and Tab2 has The buttons for Save value .

When its button(Tab2) are pressed the focus is moving to the Tab1

So. is there a way to set the focus Tab2 after submit ?

[image: Tab1]

[image: Tab2]

Thanks,
Mint

Comment: I think apex have a setting to do this. If you are using apex 5 on page designer mode click in "Atributtes" and go to something like "remember last selection" and set to yes.

Comment: Now I'm using Apex 5.1.4.00.08 . I cant set to do that U_U  Thank you for your advice

Comment: That layout don't look like as a apex 5 universal theme. but here you can see a explanation about tabs in apex 5 https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:1907:::NO::: on template options section you can see the attribute "remember active tab". if you set this option to yes, the behavior is be like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Appearance -> Template Options -> set "remember active tab" on